# event.target.value, appendChild and removeChild JS

Tags: javascript, input, addeventlistener, appendchild, removechild

I would like to do a simple program with two buttons, if i click on "+" button i want one input more , if i click "-" i want one input left.
I got two input type button (value 0 for plus and 1 for less), and a space (#addSpace) for the new inputs.
If i click on value 0 is alright, if i click 0 nothing. 
The problem in console is: *NotFoundError: Node was not found*

```
    HTML
        <div class="d-inline mx-auto" id="addSpace">
            <input name="firstvalue" placeholder="Nome studente">
        </div>

        <div class="d-block pt-5">
            <input type="button" id="aggiungi" value="0"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            <input type="button" id="togli" value="1"><i class="fas fa-less-than"></i>
        </div>

    JS
let add = document.getElementById("aggiungi");
add.addEventListener("click", moreFunction);

let less = document.getElementById("togli");
less.addEventListener("click", moreFunction);
            let space = document.querySelector("#addSpace");

    function moreFunction() {
        let line = document.createElement("input")
        line.classList.add("d-flex");
        line.classList.add("mt-3");

        if (event.target.value == 0) {
            space.appendChild(line);
        }

        if (event.target.value == 1) {
            space.removeChild(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include relevant HTML?

Comment: ok, now there should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution.

Every new input you add is given a special class `added-input`. Then when you click on the "1" button it simply looks for last input with that class.

```js
let add = document.getElementById("aggiungi");
add.addEventListener("click", moreFunction);

let less = document.getElementById("togli");
less.addEventListener("click", moreFunction);
let space = document.querySelector("#addSpace");

function moreFunction() {

    if (event.target.value == 0) {
        let line = document.createElement("input")
        line.classList.add("d-flex");
        line.classList.add("mt-3");
        line.classList.add("added-input");
        space.appendChild(line);
    }

    if (event.target.value == 1) {
        const addedInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".added-input");
        if(addedInputs.length){
            addedInputs[addedInputs.length - 1].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="d-inline mx-auto" id="addSpace">
    <input name="firstvalue" placeholder="Nome studente">
</div>

<div class="d-block pt-5">
    <input type="button" id="aggiungi" value="0"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
    <input type="button" id="togli" value="1"><i class="fas fa-less-than"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: ok it works, but I would like that only the last element was deleted

Comment: Ok I changed it to only remove that last input that was added on Button "1" click.

Comment: Awesome! Thaks you!! 
I remove the second if, i think it is not necessary.
Just " addedInputs[addedInputs.length - 1].remove();" works well.
Thanks again.

Comment: Without that if statement you will have errors thrown in the JS console when there are no items to remove.